# Address State not updating When creating new Lead via Rest API

Tags: acumatica

I'm am trying to create a new Lead in Acumatica via the REST API.  The Lead is created but, I can't seem to get the State on the Address to save.  It saves all of the other parts of the address:  AddressLine1, City, Postal Code, etc. but, not the State.  I have tried passing in both the postal abbreviation and the full name of the state.  I am doing a PUT to the endpoint to create the Lead.  This is in a SalesDemo environment on version 18.107.0022.

TIA!

Here's the JSON object that I'm putting to the endpoint:

```
{
"Activities":null,
"Address":{
  "AddressLine1":{
     "value":"123 Anystreet"
  },
  "AddressLine2":{
     "value":""
  },
  "City":{
     "value":"Anytown"
  },
  "Country":{
     "value":"US"
  },
  "PostalCode":{
     "value":"79105"
  },
  "State":{
     "value":"TX"
  },
  "id":null,
  "rowNumber":null,
  "note":null,
  "Delete":false,
  "CustomFields":null,
  "ReturnBehavior":0
},
"Attributes":null,
"BusinessAccount":null,
"Campaigns":null,
"CompanyName":null,
"ContactMethod":null,
"DateOfBirth":null,
"DoNotCall":null,
"DoNotEmail":null,
"DoNotFax":null,
"DoNotMail":null,
"Duplicate":null,
"DuplicateFound":null,
"Duplicates":null,
"Email":{
  "value":"somebody@mail.com"
},
"Fax":null,
"FaxType":null,
"FirstName":{
  "value":"John"
},
"JobTitle":null,
"LanguageOrLocale":null,
"LastIncomingActivity":null,
"LastName":{
  "value":"Doe"
},
"LastOutgoingActivity":null,
"LeadClass":null,
"LeadDisplayName":{
  "value":"Doe, John"
},
"LeadID":null,
"MarketingLists":null,
"NoMarketing":null,
"NoMassMail":null,
"Owner":null,
"OwnerEmployeeName":null,
"ParentAccount":null,
"Phone1":{
   "value":"806-867-5309"
},
"Phone1Type":null,
"Phone2":null,
"Phone2Type":null,
"Phone3":null,
"Phone3Type":null,
"Position":{
  "value":"Head of Household"
},
"Reason":null,
"Relations":null,
"Source":null,
"SourceCampaign":null,
"Status":null,
"Title":null,
"WebSite":null,
"Workgroup":null,
"WorkgroupDescription":null,
"id":null,
"rowNumber":null,
"note":null,
"Delete":false,
"CustomFields":null,
"ReturnBehavior":0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by the Branch that I sent in when I authenticated to the web API.  The Branch was not valid.  I was able to authenticate with no problems.  Once I corrected the value that I sent into the service for Branch, the state started working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code?  My guess is you're not setting the value of the node correctly.

Comment: I added the object that I'm submitting to the service.  This is not saving the State in the address.